# Reference for Euler totient function identity?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, totient-function

I'm trying to find a reference for an identity I found on the Wikipedia page on the Euler totient function:

Let $n,m > 1$ be integers and let $\omega(m)$ be the prime omega function, then
$$
\sum_{1 \leq j \leq n \atop \gcd(j,m) = 1} 1 \, = n \frac{\varphi(m)}{m} + O \left(2^{\omega(m)}\right).
$$
The equation is cited as 'Bordellès in the external links', however the link appears to be broken and I haven't had any success searching for it elsewhere.
Do any of you know where to find this identity in the literature?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this [resource](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F1-4020-2547-5_3.pdf) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No idea of a reference, but it's easily proved:
$$\sum_{\substack{j = 1 \\ (j,m) = 1}}^{n} 1 = \sum_{j = 1}^{n} \sum_{d \mid (j,m)} \mu(d) = \sum_{d \mid m} \mu(d) \sum_{\substack{j = 1 \\ j \equiv 0 \pmod{d}}}^{n} 1.$$
The sum over $j$ is equal to $\left\lfloor \frac{n}{d} \right\rfloor = \frac{n}{d} + O(1)$. So we end up with
$$n \sum_{d \mid m} \frac{\mu(d)}{d} + O\left(\sum_{d \mid m} |\mu(d)|\right) = \frac{n \varphi(m)}{m} + O(2^{\omega(m)}).$$